# PushNotification banner not showing in ios 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, push-notification

I have integrated Push notification on to my project and for some reason the banner appears on when I'm in the background mood and not when I'm in the foreground. I'm sure I've missed something, my code as bellow. Any help would much appreciate.

```
import UserNotifications
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self //not sure this is appropriate 
        registerForPushNotifications()
}
func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in

            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
    }
    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            })
        }
    }
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }

        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        if let valueInDB = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Permission_Granted") {

        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "PUSH_TOKEN")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        print("Device Push Token: \(token)")


    }
```

This gets called every time I gets a notification despite if its running on foreground or background. Thus the batch icon gets updated.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                         didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
        {

            print("Recived: \(userInfo)")

            completionHandler(.newData)

            self.onPushRecieved = MP3ViewController().catchPushNotifications
            let notification = JSON(userInfo)
            print(notification)

            let mediaId = (notification["media_id"]).stringValue
            print(mediaId)
            var badgeCount = 0
            var pushAvailable = false


            if let pushCount = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "PUSH_COUNT"){
                badgeCount = pushCount as! Int
                print(badgeCount)
                badgeCount = badgeCount + 1
                UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
            }

            print(badgeCount)
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(badgeCount, forKey: "PUSH_COUNT")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            print(isOnBackGround)
            if isOnBackGround {
                if mediaId != nil{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let mP3ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MP3ViewController") as! MP3ViewController
                        mP3ViewController.media_ID = mediaId
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mP3ViewController, animated:true)
                        self.isOnBackGround = false

                    }

                }
            }else{
                print("Running on foreground")

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol defines methods for receiving notifications and for handling actions. So whats the way to handle custom banners

Comment: @danu Where is the `delegate` methods of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to implement the following function, eg:

```
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
    completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
}
```

of this delegate: `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`